# What is the meaning of this Wolfram Alpha result when calculating $3^p = 4^q$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, logarithms

I would like to know are the some $p \in \mathbb{N}$ and $q \in\mathbb{N}$ for $3^p = 4^q$ except the trivial $p = q = 0$. So, I entered the expression into Wolfram Alpha, which returned the result for $q$:

$\displaystyle q = \frac{\log(3^p)}{\log(4)} + \frac{2\pi i c_{1}}{\log(4)}$

Nothing is said about what is $c_{1}$. Arbitrary constant? If $c_{1} \neq 0$ the result could be complex-valued I guess. I tried some calculations using the formula but the results do not make sense.

Comment: The denominator should probably be $\log 4$ instead of $\log 3$. Anyway, that $c_1$ is supposed to be an integer parameter. Mathematica's messages are, perhaps, more informative. Well, I paid good money for it :-)

Comment: You are right. I corrected the error.

Comment: Also the fundamental theorem of arithmetic tells immediately that $p=q=0$ is the only solution with $p,q$ integers.

Comment: $c_1$ must be an integer. In general, since $e^{2\pi i}=1$, complex logarithms are multi-valued. So $4^{2\pi i/\log 4}=1$.

Comment: But Wolfram Alpha is not going to restrict to natural numbers, so that formula is almost certainly not useful, except, if $p,q$ are natural numbers, then you can say $c_1=0$. The resulting formula won't help, though.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It will (or will try to) if you tell it to. I tried http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+3%5Ep+%3D+4%5Eq+in+integers

Comment: For some idea of a baseline, try the query "solve 2^p = 4^q in integers".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Other's have discussed the output given by Wolfram|Alpha, so I'll provide only a hint for a solution.

**Hint**: For every $p \in \mathbb N$ with $p\geq 1$, we have that $4^p$ is even but $3^p$ is odd. A natural number [cannot](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16947/proving-there-is-no-natural-number-which-is-both-even-and-odd) be both even and odd, so...

Answer (score 3):

So to find all solutions, real and complex consider the definition of an exponential. $a^b=e^{b\log a}$. Also helps to mention that the complex logarithm of a complex number $r e^{it}$ is $\log\mid r \mid+2n\pi i$ with $n$ an integer. It's to do with the fact that the logarithm function is the inverse of a function that isn't one to one so you've to choose a 'branch'. Anyway...

Now write as $ e^{p\log 3} = e^{4\log q} $.

Take the complex log of both sides so that

$p\log 3 + 2n\pi i=q\log 4$ where $n$ is an integer and then divide across

Comment: This answer was helpful too!