# What does the big cap notation mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm trying to understand [How can an ordered pair be expressed as a set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62908/how-can-an-ordered-pair-be-expressed-as-a-set) and I don't know what the big cap/cup notations mean when placed next to an ordered pair: $\bigcap(a,b)$ and $\bigcup(a,b)$.

Comment: It mean union $\cup$ or intersection $\cap$ of sets in $(a,b)$.

Comment: @Sasha So it only makes sense if $a$ and $b$ are sets. :)

Comment: The cap is intersection, the cup is union. Remember that the ordered pair $(a,b)$ is just shorthand notation for the set $ \{ \{ a \} , \{a,b\} \}$.

Comment: In the question you linked to $(a,b)$ represented a set of sets.  Then $\cup (a,b)$ denoted the union of those sets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually answered in the linked question, but for clarification, if by definition $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ then $$\bigcap(a,b) = \bigcap\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\} = \{a\} \cap \{a,b\} = \{a\}$$ and $$\bigcup(a,b) = \bigcup\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\} = \{a\} \cup \{a,b\} = \{a,b\}.$$