# Equality of n-tuples of different lengths

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Enderton's 2001 book on mathematical logic, it is stated on page 4 that "every ordered triple is also an ordered pair". More generally, Enderton states that if $<x_1, ...,x_m>=<y_1, ...,y_n>$, it is not necessary that $m=n.$

Could someone point out what definition of equality is used for these statements, and if such a definition is standard? It does not seem to be stated in the said book.

Comment: You may want to check [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2122856/123852).

Comment: it should be $n$ in one of the tuples right?

Comment: @dave yes, sorry for the typo.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Thanks for the link - I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to encode an $n$ tuple $< x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n >$ as a pair $ <<x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n-1}>, x_n> $. This way as you can represent all finite tuples as a pair.  You can get an equality that Enderton describes by having  a tuple that matches the representation.