# Von Neumann Universe V, rank and every set contained in V

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I sought a consistent definition for the rank of set and I found the definition of Von Neumann universe to define the rank of a set as follows:

The cumulative hierarchy is defined by transfinite recursion over all ordinals by

- $V_0=\emptyset$,
- $V_{\alpha+1}=\mathcal P(V_\alpha)$, and
- $V_\alpha=\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}V_\beta$

Then, the rank of a set $S$ is the smallest $\alpha$ such that $S \subseteq \alpha$. But I don't understand how does any mathematical set (for instance a real set) could be include in a $V_\alpha$ whereas $V_\alpha$ contains a construction of empty set like that

```
    V0 = { },
    V1 = {{ }},
    V2 = {{ }, {{ }}},
    V3 = {{}, {{ }}, {{ }, {{ }}}},
    etc.
```

I saw that Von Neumann set the natural set with that method, but in the ZFC theory is there a result that proves it exists a bijection between any set and that ranked construction of Von Neumann please?

I have never studied neither the set theory nor the ZFC theory before but I would like to understand that point.

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your $V_3$ is wrong - it should have *four* elements. $V_3=\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\{\emptyset\}\}, \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}$. (I've abbreviated "$\{\}$" as "$\emptyset$" for readability.)

*A good exercise: what's the cardinality of $V_n$?*

You ask where in $V$ do common mathematical objects, like $\{1\}$, lie. Well, the view of set theory is that mathematical objects *are* sets built up from the empty set. E.g. $0$ is $\{\}$, $1$ is $\{\{\}\}$, etc. - these are the [finite ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number). A rational number is an equivalence class of [ordered triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair) of finite ordinals (sign, numerator, denominator), and a real number is [a set of rational numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut). *(This is merely one way to do the coding; there are other ways.)* The role of set theory as a foundation of mathematics comes from the observation that *all of mathematics can be developed within $V$*. It's difficult to make this precise, since what is "all of mathematics?", but there is a lot of writing on this subject.

*There are also plenty of objections to this approach, on the grounds that it is extremely artificial and nonintuitive; see e.g. [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308422/why-do-we-accept-kuratowskis-definition-of-ordered-pairs) addressing the treatment of ordered pairs specifically, and [this mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90820/set-theories-without-junk-theorems) addressing some of the artificial phenomena which arise in general from this approach. A very different sort of object, [structural set theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/structural+set+theory), is often advocated in this context. One intermediate approach is via set theory with [urelements](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ZFA), and this has the benefit of not being too different from classical set theory.*

Comment: Thank you for your expanded answer but you haven't completely answered my question . You say "Well, the view of set theory is that mathematical objects are sets built up from the empty set. E.g. 0 is {}, 1 is {{}}, etc", I already understood that when I talked about the construction of natural set with the Von Neumann method, but is there a result that proves it exists a kind of "surjection" between the construction from empty set and any set? May we exhibit a case where we don't construct the set of any possible sets with VN method but where this result stay true? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Wmog I'm not sure I understand your question, but maybe you're asking whether we can prove in ZFC that every set is in $V$? The answer is yes to this question, and the crucial axiom is [**Foundation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity): if $\alpha_0$ were a set not in $V$, it would have to have an element $\alpha_1$ not in $V$; and proceeding this way we can construct a sequence of sets $\alpha_0\ni \alpha_1\ni \alpha_2\ni ...$, contradicting Foundation. Does this answer your question? If this is not your question, can you elaborate on it?