# Why does the imaginary number $i$ satisfy $i\times 0=0$?

Tags: complex-numbers

Why does the imaginary number $i$ satisfy $i\times 0=0$?
I mean, we don't really know what $i$ is. How could we be sure about that? I think there's a reason behind why mathematicians decided that.

Comment: We've understood complex numbers for a few centuries now; the meaning of mathematical word "imaginary" hasn't had any relation to the meaning of the English word "imaginary" for a long time.

Comment: We know what $i$ is, it's $\sqrt{-1}$...

Comment: How is closing this helpful? It is clear what the question is, and it is a good un'! It is also not obvious to me how to prove $0\times i=0$ given simply that $i^2=-1$. It is a theorem, not something we have decided. Thus, an answer will prove this theorem! (As, for example, user13157 has done.)

Comment: @user1729 Actually this is most often not a theorem but a trivial consequence of the construction of `C`. Which brings us to the problem with this question, which could be that, apparently, the OP believes that the number `i` exists per se, separately of everything else, while (as you know) `i` is simply one element of a precisely defined set. Ultimately, we do not know what `C`is to the OP and the question only makes sense if the OP explains this (the trouble being that, as soon as one has a precise definition of `C`at hand, the problem disappears--but let us forget this point for now).

Comment: @Did Hmm, I don't know. How do you define $\mathbb{C}$ if not as "the real numbers with an element $i$ such that $i^2=-1$"? (Implicitly, we assume brackets work as we like.) Then the result follows according to user13157's proof (and I remember people struggling with the analogous proof in a first course on rings - I do not think "trivial" is really the best word!).

Comment: (@Did I should say: you do make a good point, and although I do still think the question should be reopened I am less confident in my opinion now - the OP needs to define $\mathbb{C}$ (but, of course, it is not rigorously defined when you first encounter it, is it? So I perhaps think this question should be reopened so that the OP can understand how to see $i\times0=0$ using different definitions). Anyway, when I read this question I did not see this issue *and therefore I do not believe the OP would see it either!* This is why people need to comment when closing questions.)

Comment: @user1729 Nobody ever defined C as "the real numbers with an element i such that i2=−1" for me, and I am glad they did not perform this exercise of cruelty on me. :-) No wonder people have problems with C if one defines it for them like that.

Comment: @Did What, not even in highschool? Maybe my memory is fuzzy...I am going to dig out one of my old books now, to see what it says...

Comment: @Did I have three relevant books on my desk: *Calculus: A complete Course* by Robert A. Adams, *Engineering Mathematics* by K.A.Stroud, and *Fundamentals of University Mathematics* by McGregor, Nimmo and Stothers. The first two, Adams and Stroud, go for the "$i^2=-1$ and complex numbers have the form $ai+b$, $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$" definition, while McGregor, Nimmo and Stothers start with the complex plane and work backwards. So...I would think that the "extension" was quite common. No?

Comment: @user1729 To sum up, "not a theorem but a trivial consequence of the construction of C", no? Which brings us back to the necessity that the OP explains what is C to them.

Comment: @Did I am not seeing the triviality here - $0\times(a+bi)=0\times a+0\times bi=0\times i=\ldots?$

Comment: @user1729 If the multiplication is defined on $\mathbb R^2$ by $(a,b)\times(c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$ and $\mathbf 0$ defined as $(0,0)$, then $\mathbf 0\times i=(0,0)\times(0,1)=\ldots$

Comment: @Did Ah, I understand. But as I said in my earlier comment - only one of the three books on my shelf define $\mathbb{C}$ like this (McGregor et al.). But, I suppose, Adams just has complex numbers as an appendix, while Stroud is written for engineers(!). However however, I suppose one could ask "*why* do we define complex multiplication like this?" In the sense that, thinking of complex numbers as extensions of the reals is much more natural. Anyway, I have an exam to write so I shall stop contemplating definitions now. Think I might put in a really nasty question about $0\times i$ though...

Comment: @user1729 Hamilton's construction of $\,\Bbb C\,$ as pairs of reals is a very special case of normal form algorithms for quotient rings. In particular, if you apply the general algorithm to $\,\Bbb R[x]/(x^2\!+1)\,$ then you obtain precisely Hamilton representation of $\,\Bbb C.\,$ It's analogous pulling back the ring operations of $\,\Bbb Z/m\,$ to the normal reps $\,\{0,1,2\,\ldots\, m\!-\!1\}.\,$ For details [see this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/646600/242)

Comment: @BillDubuque: Did is only expressing his opinion. Besides, if I delete that comment, then it disrupts the thread with user1729. I myself am surprised that $\mathbb{C}$ is introduced in another manner than an extension field of $\mathbb{R}$, that is, $\mathbb{R}[i]$ where $i^2=-1$. I learned it that way, but I have no idea how one would view that approach if they started with a different approach. However, Did never does say how $\mathbb{C}$ was introduced to him. I would be interested to know that, but *not* here :-)

Comment: @rob Based on above comments, I suspect the other approach refers to Hamilton's pair construction. As I explain in the answer linked in my prior comment, it is essentially the standard quotient ring, only expressed with reps being the simplest (least degree) elements of the cosets. Strangely, the general idea behind this is not as well-known (to non-algebraists) as it should be. Better to let Did's comment stand. I'll simply add another general comment and be happy with that. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: @robjohn "Did never does say how ℂ was introduced to him" See comment Jul 30 at 12:47.

Comment: @robjohn If you want to learn more about the general way in which complex numbers were intorduced to Did, look up the "third" book I mention in my comments above, *Fundamentals of University Mathematics* by McGregor, Nimmo and Stothers. The main advantage of this method, as I see it, is that you start with the complex plane. So it is more geometric and less algebraic.

Comment: @Did: Okay, I see. Instead of being written as $x+yi$, complex numbers are written as $(x,y)$. Thanks.

Comment: @rob Yes, that's the Hamilton defintion of $\,\Bbb C\,$ as *pairs* of reals (that I mention above).  For much further discussion see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2658/242) which touches on the interesting history of complex numbers.

Comment: @robjohn Yes. While we are at it, I am curious to know your opinion on a recent comment mentioning "users wander[ing] outside of their expertise", [users] "post[ing] dubious quality material - apparently encouraged by confidence inspired by high rep", "big egos" and "users stray[ing] outside their expertise". Are you condoning such considerations? Do you see them as in accordance with the m.se model?

Comment: @Did: that comment has been removed. I don't want to go off-topic and discuss this here. This is better left to chat. I will say that there is no restriction that people need to be "experts" to try to explain things they feel they understand to others. Upvotes and downvotes will usually separate the chaff.

Comment: @robjohn Lots of comments are removed these days, let us hope that these shoot-and-erase tactics do not spread. Not answering comments discussing the merits of other users behind their back would have been preferable (especially, a mod should know better). Personally I disagree that these matters should be discussed in chat, first and foremost because not all users (desire to) go regularly there (but I do not know if this is accepted canon). On the other hand, your comment about "experts" is welcomed.

Comment: @Did: we are straying off-topic here again, but what I said there was that communications on the net can easily get misconstrued. It was an attempt at moderating the situation. If you don't want to continue such conversations in chat, then a general discussion in meta would be my next suggestion. An extended comment thread is not the right place.

Comment: @robjohn Would meta not be preferrable to chat for such a discussion? After all, meta retains conversations while chat does not, and meta is less dependent on who is online as any given time.

Comment: Related (to the maths question... :-)): http://math.stackexchange.com/a/887732/

Comment: @user1729: there is a mechanism in chat to encapsulate conversations, and even to post a link to them in comments if desired. Chat is preferable when particular people or instances are being discussed. Meta is better for more general concerns, like policies. Sometimes, it is hard to separate the two, however. The point I was trying to make was that this thread keeps drifting off-topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ignore this answer if you've never heard of matrix multiplication. Better yet, [learn matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) and then read this answer!

The answer to your question depends on what definition of complex numbers you're using.

For example, I like to think of the complex numbers as matrices of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & -b \\ b & a
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. This allows us to define two complex numbers
\begin{align*}
\mathbf 0
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} &
i
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
Hence we have the identity
$$
\mathbf 0\cdot i
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\cdot 0+0\cdot 1 & 0\cdot(-1)+0\cdot 0\\
0\cdot 0+0\cdot 1 & 0\cdot (-1)+0\cdot 0
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
=
\mathbf0
$$

One of the nice things about defining the complex numbers this way is that we avoid the confusing equation $i=\sqrt{-1}$. We also don't have to resort to using silly words like "imaginary."

Note, however, that we do have
$$
i^2
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}^2
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So, if we define the complex number
$$
\mathbf{1}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
then we recover the formula
$$
i^2=-\mathbf{1}
$$
To convince yourself that our definition of the complex number $\mathbf1$ is not arbitrary, note that $\mathbf 1$ enjoys the property
$$
\mathbf 1
\begin{pmatrix}
a & -b \\
b & a
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a & -b \\
b & a
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a & -b \\
b & a
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This is remarkably similar to the celebrated equation $1\cdot a=a$. It's also worth noting that the complex number $\mathbf0$ satisfies
$$
\mathbf0+
\begin{pmatrix}
a & -b \\
b & a
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\0&0
\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix}
a & -b \\
b & a
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0+a & 0-b \\
0+b & 0+a
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a & -b \\
b & a
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which is similar to our usual equation $0+a=a$.

The point here is that complex-arithmetic "feels" like ordinary arithmetic but is indeed different. As @Hurkyl points out, algebraic gadgets that behave like this are called [rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)).

Answer (score 6):

Just like real numbers, we can write: $0z = (0+0)z = 0z + 0z$. Canceling like terms on each side allows us to see that $0 = 0z$.  Thus, this is really a property of zero itself.

Also, as others have mentioned, complex numbers (including imaginaries) are fairly well understood.  However, one important nuance is that @iHubble's definition quickly leads to contradictions (such as using properties of square roots to show that $-1 = i^2 = \sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1} = \sqrt{(-1)^2} = 1$).  It is best to instead always define $i$ as a number such that $i^2 = -1$.

Comment: It's not a "property of zero itself". Rather, it is a property of any algebraic structure (e.g. ring) which satisfies the laws that you employed in your proof, e.g. the distributive law, and additive cancellation law.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I think he means it is a property of $0$ in any ring, in this case, $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @robjohn Possibly. The point of my comment was to help clarify that, i.e. to whittle it down to the algebraic essence of the matter (which may not be so clear to readers who have not had much experience with abstract algebra)

Answer (score 5):

The complex numbers are defined to satisfy all of the usual ring axioms: i.e. all of the usual identities involving $0,1,+,-,\times,\div$ hold for complex numbers. $0z=0$ is one of those identities.

Answer (score 5):

Technically, $0\,i\not\in\mathbb{R}$; instead, $0\,i\in\mathbb{C}$. Thus, being (overly?) pedantic, $0\times i\ne0$; instead $0\times i=0+0\,i$. However, being the zero element of $\mathbb{C}$, we usually abbreviate $0+0\,i$ as $0$, not meaning an element of $\mathbb{R}$ but an element of the subset of $\mathbb{C}$ that is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, that is $\{x+0\,i:x\in\mathbb{R}\}$. With this abbreviation, we *do* have $0\times i=0$

---

[This comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14828/set-theoretic-definition-of-numbers/14842#comment32352_14828) by AlexB says

> The thing is that when one defines the integers, they come with a canonical embedding of $\mathbb{N}$. Similarly, the rationals come with a canonical embedding of $\mathbb{Z}$ and so on. So it does make sense to speak of subsets. Indeed, it becomes so cumbersome to distinguish between genuine subsets and images under an embedding that one fairly quickly drops this distinction in practice, unless one really has to thing about the foundations.

The question "Why does the imaginary number $i$ satisfy $i\times0=0$?" seems to me to be fairly foundational, so I think that my approach above seems appropriate.

Once we have established why $i\times0=0$, then we can move on as Arturo Magidin says in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/14842):

> So even though they are actually very different sets, we have copies of each sitting inside the "next one", copies that respect all the structures we are interested in, so we can still think of them as being "subsets".

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I am not convinced by your pedantry. (Although it certainly made me think!) Are you also claiming that $i^2=-1\not\in\mathbb{R}$? (Mainly I am not convinced because, if we adopt the language of rings which seems to be the fashion in these answers, $0i$ is contained in the subring $\mathbb{R}$, $0i\in\mathbb{R}$. No?)

Comment: @user1729: $\mathbb{R}$ is one-dimensional. $\{x+0\,i:x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is a one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{C}$. They are isomorphic, but not the same. It is possible that after $\mathbb{C}$ is introduced, $\mathbb{R}$ could be redefined to be this one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{C}$, but this feels circular to me.

Comment: Another downvote without comment? Consider this: is $(0,0)\in\mathbb{R}$? How can $\mathbb{R}$ be a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ when we can't even define $\mathbb{C}$ without $\mathbb{R}$ so that either $\mathbb{C}=\{x+iy:x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$ or $\mathbb{C}=\{(x,y):x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$. There seems to be a confusion between $\mathbb{R}$ and the subspace of $\mathbb{C}$ that is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: There is a well-established tradition in mathematics of *identification* that permeates it at all levels. This practice is endlessly convenient and enlightening. E.g. we identify things with other things in order to get $\Bbb N\subset\Bbb Z\subset\Bbb Q\subset\Bbb R\subset\Bbb C$. It's true that on a machine-language level, pedantry is useful for rigorous constructions, but after the constructions are done or trivial or subconscious and we've moved on, it is no longer useful but distracting and gets in the way of intuitively seeing the big picture and what's "morally correct."

Comment: @blue: yes, I agree. However, the question "why does $i\times0=0$?" seems pretty "low level", so I thought that being pedantic was appropriate.

Comment: @blue: I have added some quotes that support what I am saying. I am not trying to say that we need always to make the distinction between $\mathbb{R}$ and the canonical subspace of $\mathbb{C}$, but when asking a question like "why does $i\times0=0$?" I think it is a good idea.

Comment: @Rob $ $ If $\,\Bbb R$ is disjoint from $\Bbb C\,$ and $\,0\in\Bbb R,\ i\in\Bbb C,\,$ then what do you mean by the "product" $\,0\,i\,$ when you write $\,0\,i\not\in\Bbb R,\,$ i.e. what type of "product" is denoted? $ $ It cannot denote the multiplication *operation* of a ring since the operands are from disjoint rings.

Comment: @BillDubuque: $\mathbb{C}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with basis $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ and an additional vector space product defined by $(a,b)\times(c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$ (the field product). So it makes sense to multiply by a scalar $0\cdot(0,1)=(0,0)$ and by a vector $(0,0)\times(0,1)=(0,0)$.

Comment: That's what I figured. So the next question is, do you think that the product in the OP's question denotes a scalar product vs. ring multiplication? If so, why?

Comment: That's a good question. I had assumed that he intended $0\in\mathbb{R}$, not $0+0\,i\in\mathbb{C}$; otherwise; I wouldn't see a problem arising.

Comment: @Rob What if the question was instead about $\,0+i\,?$ How would you handle that given that the summands are from disjoint rings.

Comment: @BillDubuque: The only problem would arise if we were considering $0\in\mathbb{R}$. Then we would need to "promote" $0$ to $(0,0)$ via the canonical embedding. It turns out that with products, whether we multiply by scalar or the canonical embedding, we get the same thing.

Comment: @robjohn Thank you for this answer! Along these lines, shouldn't we really describe Euler's equation as $e^{i\pi} = -1 + 0i$ ? Is it as pretty if we don't neglect that the RHS is in the complex plane and say that $Re(e^{i\pi}) = -1$?

Comment: @Shape: if you want to be overly pedantic, then yes, I guess we could write $e^{i\pi}=1+0i$. However, we usually omit zero and write $1=1+0i\in\mathbb{C}$; usually, we only write $1+0i$ if we need to **emphasize** that $1\in\mathbb{C}$. Since we have the complex expression $e^{i\pi}$, it is pretty clear that we are dealing with the complex plane.