# Is 1 ∈ K, and hence 0 ∈ K, true for all fields K?

Tags: field-theory

Given that **K** is an arbitrary field, is it true that 1 ∈ **K**, and hence 0 ∈ **K**?

Comment: By definition of a field, there is a $0$ and a $1$ element, typically called the additive and multiplicative identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A field $K$ will always have an additive identity - called "$0_K$" - and a multiplicative identity - called "$1_K$." *(And it's worth noting that one of the field axioms asserts that these are distinct.)* So in this sense the answer to your question is "yes."

However, note the subscripts in my previous paragraph! There is not a single thing "$0$" which is an element of every field - one field's additive identity need not be in a different field. Each field has *its own* additive and multiplicative identity, but asking "Is $0\in K$?" falls prey to a subtle confusion.

We do often write "$0, 1$" instead of "$0_K, 1_K$" *when there's only one field being talked about*, or *when all the fields being talked about share the same additive and multiplicative identities* (e.g. the fields $\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$ all "overlap"$^1$). But this is technically an abuse of notation.

---

$^1$Well, [as usually understood](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/14842/28111). But this is a case where it's valuable to ignore the set theorists (of which I am one).

Comment: This is a bit of a tangent to the original question, but based on your answer, does one need to prove that 1 ∈ **K** in besides proving that x + y ∈ K, x - y ∈ K, x * y ∈ K, and x/y ∈ K, where x,y ∈ K, in order to show that the set K is a field.